# How to use the wireframe and a scater3d at the same time using GLMakie in Julia?

Tags: plot, julia, julia-plots, makie.jl

Ive been working with adjustments and I have coordinates and I need to plot a sphere with wireframe, I need to draw these points and this sphere on the same graph, how to do this using GLMakie in Julia? I can use wireframe and scatter separately, but not both at the same plot.
And also, how can i change the center of the sphere with the command Sphere(Point3(1,5)?
I tried it..

```
x = [0, 1]
y = [0, 1]
z = [0, 1]
scatter!(x, y, z, markersize=[0.2,0.0])
wireframe!(Sphere(Point3(1),5), limits=FRect3D([-5,-5,-5],[10,10,10]))
```

but returned: Combined{Makie.wireframe, Tuple{Sphere{Int64}}}

Answer (score 0):

you need to display the figure, the quick and dirty way is to run

```
current_figure()
```

Comment: Apparently it didn't work, can you give me examples of how to use current to plot a wireframe and scatter at the same time? Thank you